# C# - CheckBox height if off by 1 pixel from what it is set to

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

Using the method `SetPropertyBulk` to set the height of a CheckBox to 16, its actual height ends up being an extra 1 pixel higher (17).

Relevant methods:

```
    public IEnumerable<Control> GetAllControls(Control parentControl, Type type = null)
    {
        var controls = parentControl.Controls.Cast<Control>();

        if (type != null)
        {
            return
                controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetAllControls(ctrl, type))
                    .Concat(controls)
                    .Where(c => c.GetType() == type);
        }
        return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetAllControls(ctrl)).Concat(controls);
    }

    public void SetPropertyBulk(string propertyS, object val, Type t = null,
        Control parentControl = null)
    {
        Control parent = parentControl ?? _f;

        foreach (Control c in GetAllControls(parent, t))
        {
            PropertyInfo p;

            try
            {
                p = c.GetType().GetProperty(propertyS,
                    BindingFlags.Public
                    | BindingFlags.Instance
                    | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
            }
            catch (AmbiguousMatchException)
            {
                p = c.GetType().GetProperty(propertyS,
                    BindingFlags.Public
                    | BindingFlags.Instance
                    | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
                Debug.Print($"Ambiguous match for property {propertyS} " +
                            $"in control {c}");
            }       

            if (p != null && p.CanWrite)
            {
                try
                {
                    p.SetValue(c, val, null);
                    Debug.Print($"================\n" +
                                $"Set property\n" +
                                $"Type: {c}\n" +
                                $"Property: {p.Name}\n" +
                                $"Value: {val}\n" +
                                $"Check: {p.GetValue(c)}");
                }
                catch (ArgumentException)
                {
                    Debug.Print(
                        $"The given value {val} is not valid for the " +
                        $"given property {propertyS} in control {c}.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Print($"The given property {propertyS} does not " +
                            $"exist for control {c}.");
            }
        }
    }

    public void SetPropertyBulk(string propertyS, object val, ICollection<Type> t,
        Control parentControl = null)
    {
        foreach (Type type in t)
        {
            SetPropertyBulk(propertyS, val, type);
        }
    }
```

I'm calling the methods in the form load event like so:

```
        const int cHeight = 16;

        SetPropertyBulk("Height", cHeight,
            new List<Type>
            {
                typeof(Label),
                typeof(CheckBox),
                typeof(TextBox),
                typeof(NumericUpDown)
            });
        SetPropertyBulk("MinimumSize", new Size(0, cHeight),
            new List<Type> {typeof(Label), typeof(CheckBox)});
        SetPropertyBulk("AutoSize", true,
            new List<Type> {typeof(Label), typeof(CheckBox)});
```

I'm checking the value of the height property like so:

```
        Debug.Print($"Check Top: {GenChkScreen.Top}");
        Debug.Print($"Check Bottom: {GenChkScreen.Bottom}");
        Debug.Print($"Check Height: {GenChkScreen.Height}");
```

And it returns:

> Check Top: 15
>   Check Bottom: 32
>   Check Height: 17

I also have a `Debug.Print` in `SetPropertyBulk`, which for the CheckBox returns:

> ================
>   Set property
>   Type: System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox, CheckState: 0
>   Property: Height
>   Value: 16
>   Check: 16

The former debug output returns a height of 17, but `PropertyInfo.GetValue()` in the latter debug output returns a height of 16. By setting the CheckBox's `BackColor` property to a colour different from the form and counting the pixels, the actual size of the CheckBox is 17.

Why is the height not being set to 16? Why is `PropertyInfo.GetValue()` returning the wrong height (or, unbeknownst to me, the height is being changed again after being set in `SetPropertyBulk`.)

Comment: if you remove the `AutoSize` does it still change size?  Otherwise my only other thought is that there's a built in limitation, maybe check the source?

Comment: @cjb110 Yes, setting `AutoSize` to `false` does allow the height to be set to 16. This made me realise my mistake, which was that I never set the `MaximumSize` to 16 as well, to prevent `AutoSize` from going over.

Comment: The correct way to mark your question as being answered is to accept an answer (by using the check mark next to the appropriate answer) rather than to edit your question and add the words "Solved" in either the title or the body. Please respect the appropriate conventions of this site.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever cjb110 posted a comment, therefore I cannot mark it as an answer (even though the comment didn't directly answer the question anyway.) I can not mark my own answer as solved because I have to wait two days. My thinking is: why waste people's time by having them click this question only for it to be already solved?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I didn't set the `MaximumSize` to 16 as well to prevent `AutoSize` from going over.